# asp.net ajax, change asp:image imageurl

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I have an update panel within which a sortable grid is present. While sorting, I have to change an image which shows the sort direction. The sort is an ajax operation initiated by a linkbutton for each column. Everything works fine except the image control.
I am able to toggle visible property to show and hide it but, not able to change the ImageUrl property.

```
imagesort.ImageUrl = "~/images/asc.jpg";            
imagesort.Visible = true;
```

The above code shows the image but the image is always the imageurl given in the markup not what is set in the code. If imageurl is not specified in the markup, no image(broken image) is shown irrespective of the above code.

Answer (score -1):

When I had this problem, My HTMLImageControl was in a repeater, on which I just called DataBind(). This was feasible in my case.

You might want to set the image URL in the client side javascript on button click.

Comment: can you explain why it is not able to change imageurl property when other properties like visible can be changed?

Comment: dont know for sure. I guess it does change the imageurl. but  it requires fetching the new image from the server and this is not included in your ajax call. Changing the imageurl is just about setting a new attribute. But it wont work unless the image is fetched from the server.



Just my guess

Comment: finally decided to use 2 images and toggle visibility according to sort

Answer (score -1):

```
document.getElementById('<%=Image1.ClientID%>').setAttribute('src', val);
```

Comment: Would you like to help fighting the misconception that StackOverflow is a free code writing service? Please augment your code-only answer with some explanation.